# Insert data from a form into a table

Tags: vba, ms-access

It's been probably 3 years since I have had to use VB or VBA code. I am working on a project for work using Microsoft Access where I need to take the information that is listed on the form and insert it into a table. What I am stuck on is the last part of the code the values part. This is what I have so far.

```
INSERT Volunteers (Name, Email, Number, Emergency Contact, Emergency Number) VALUES (and this is where I get stuck)
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Would be best to show the rest of your existing code

Answer (score 0):

You want the [single-record table append query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ff834799.aspx):

```
INSERT INTO Volunteers (Name, Email, Number, Emergency Contact, Emergency Number) 
VALUES ("Value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Value4", "Value5")
```

Assuming you are constructing the SQL statement in the code-behind of the form, you can access the controls by name:

```
Dim sql As String
sql = _
    "INSERT INTO Volunteers (Name, Email, Number, Emergency Contact, Emergency Number)  " & _
    "VALUES (""" & txbName & """, """ & txbEmail & """, """ & txbNumber & """, """ & txbEmergencyContact & """, """ & txbEmergencyNumber & ")"
```

(All those triple-quotes are to get a double-quote (`"`) into the final SQL statement, for text fields; numeric fields don't need any delimiter, and date fields use the `#` as a delimiter.)
If you are adding values from a different form, you can access them like so:

```
Forms!OtherForm!ControlName
```

and values in a subform (IIRC):

```
SubformControl.Form!ControlName
```

See [here](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm) for more details.